# routing app localization error while uploading on iTunes store

Tags: app-store-connect

To configure this app as an iOS routing app, upload a routing app coverage file on the app's Version page in My Apps on iTunes Connect.

This error is coming while uploading to iTunes store. I have not attached any json file  in coverage file. it was optional so i leave it as it is. why is the error?

[snapshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKHC5.png)

Comment: no answers . i am getting shocked?

Comment: Dont worry guys I got the answer

Comment: where is error ?